# Change video playbackRate to match form input value

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, video, html5-video

I'm trying to adjust video speed based on a form's input value for an ios app I'm building in Cordova. I've been able to change the playbackRate, but need to make it dynamic by adding user input. Any idea how to do this?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="speed" type="text" placeholder="Input Speed" 
name="speed">
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-large" id="formtest">Form 
Test</button>
```

JS:

```
var speed = document.getElementsByName("speed")[0].value;

document.getElementById('formtest').onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById('trail1').play();
    document.getElementById('trail1').playbackRate = 1/speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the input type to number.

I would be tempted to use an onchange event listener and handler for this but of course you can just use onclick.

```
var speed = document.getElementsByName("speed")[0];

speed.onclick = function(){

    var rate = speed.value;

   document.getElementById('trail1').play();
   document.getElementById('trail1').playbackRate = rate; 

};
```

Then you can just input the speed you want the video to play at.

Also you have the name attribute twice in the input element.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've decided to build this in Meteor. What kind of stuff do I need to have on the backend to get the app to read the value?

Sorry. Relative coding noob here

Comment: Am I right to assume you will use an asteroid to access the methods on the meteor back end? Is there any reason you chose the use Meteor or is it just your preferred option?

Comment: @TravisJohn Do you notice the playback skip when they change the playbackrate on your iphone?